# Is it possible to customize the indicator in front of a file in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode put an annoying red icon in front of my java file.

I don't even know what the thing is called. is it called an indicator? plz feel free to correct me.

[image]

Is it possible to customize the indicator, like change the color?

Comment: Yes, among other things, extensions in VS Code can change the icons shown in the file navigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code has extensions, and among other types of extensions are icon packs which change the icons you'll see for files like you're showing here.

So, open the extension finder, and search for icon packs and install one that suits your fancy.

Comment: It's called Icon Theme. Here is an example: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme